# Is Parallel Computing Toolbox Supported by Matlab Coder?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I am developing a parallel application using the Matlab parallel computing toolbox. I am wondering if I can convert the application using Matlab Coder for C/C++? Can Parallel Application developed using Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox be converted to C/C++ by Matlab Coder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB coder doesn't support Parallel Computing Toolbox. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/description2.html for the supported functionality.

You can however deploy using the compiler applications using Parallel Computing.

Comment: Do you mean you can use commands like `parfor` without error but also without speedup?

Comment: You can deploy a MATLAB application which opens a `matlabpool` and then calls `parfor` - so you do get speedup.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB Coder does in fact support PARFOR for code generation as of R2013b:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/parfor.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/release-notes.html

It has been supported in MEX since R2012b (see release notes again).